# "За были..." Как отредактировать?

Tags: пунктуация, смысл, редактура

**Обеими руками за были за катарско-турецкий газопровод и в Европе.**

Как бы отредактировать, чтоб и на слух фраза не оставалась курьёзной?

Comment: За чем Вам тут два ЗА?

Comment: Это цитата. Хороша тем, что навела на мысль о правильном месте в предложении оборота с предлогом на конце. Только — в хвосте!

Comment: "За" непременно кавычится, точка всегда за закрывающей кавычкой.

Comment: Формально, и в середине фразы, — да. Но озвучение кавычек не передаёт.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"И в Европе за катарско-турецкий газопровод были обеими руками за."

Answer (score 3):

И Европа была обеими руками «за» газопровод Катар – Турция.

Comment: Стоит выделить «за»? А смысл есть?

Comment: Обязательно, иначе оно будет просто предлогом к газопроводу.Сравните : Кто «за»?

Comment: Так на слух — и слышится предлогом.

Comment: Тут двойная роль.Розенталь парагр 138.Идиома «обеими руками "за"»,одобрять и предложная роль. Идиома первична,приоритетна.

Comment: Если роль не совсем предложная, то выделением одного звена оборот рвётся на части.

Answer (score 1):

*Обеими руками были за катарско-турецкий газопровод и в Европе*. Это по минимуму.

Дальше уже можно править сколь душе угодно.